# Call procedure with arguments

Tags: vba

I have a procedure:

```
Sub a_fillValueByCells(sheet As Worksheet, v As String)
    Set cellNames = produceCellNames(Row, cs)
    For Each cell In cellNames
        MsgBox cell
    Next
End Sub
```

And I want to call it:

```
Set localSheet = ActiveSheet
Dim v As String
Set v = dataSheet.Range(cellName("B", Row))    
a_fillValueByCells (localSheet, v)
```

But  I get error on last line in edittion time:

> Expected: =

If I'll remove last argument:

```
a_fillValueByCells (localSheet)
```

Why I get error message and how can I fix it ?
Thanks

Comment: I think your method names are confusing. Consider changing `a_fillValueByCells` to `FillValueByCells`. Also the `_` underscore makes it look like this method is an event handler for event `fillValueByCells` of `WithEvents` object `a` declared at instance level; it's the convention VB6/VBA uses for event handler procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by changing:

```
a_fillValueByCells (localSheet, v)
```

to

```
a_fillValueByCells sheet:=localSheet, v:=v
```

**Update**

I have found another one solution - just remove the parenthesis:

```
a_fillValueByCells localSheet, v
```

Comment: If you want to keep the parenthesis you can also add `Call` in front of your method call - but that's archaic and rather ugly. Kudos (+1) for finding it all by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `Set v = dataSheet.Range(cellName("B", Row))` to

`v = dataSheet.Range(cellName("B", Row)).Text`

Since yours returns a Range instead of a String.

Comment: sorry, strings does not need set... `v = dataSheet.Range(cellName("B", Row)).Text` should do.